# Find Thevenin equivalent of given circuit with two voltage sources

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I have to find Thevenin equivalent circuit between M and N.
So I understand that I have to get rid of R7, and find voltage of Vm and Vn, then Vth = Vm-Vn.
But I don't understand how to calculate it. The two opposite voltage sources trip me out.
[image]

As for Rth, I calculate it as R8/R7/(R4+(R5/R6)) and get the result 3.75kohms.

I want to understand this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: So after simplifying the circuit, I calculate I1 = 0.5 mA and I2 = 0, then Vmn = 10 x 0.5 = 5 (V).

Is this correct?
[image]

Comment: Simplify the resistances on the right hand side and compute the current in the single loop. Then figure out the voltage difference across M,N.

Comment: I might understand why you removed R7 first, but your calculation even without R7 is incorrect and you still need to add the R7 back to the circuit or you won't have a correct result.

Comment: Is R7 part of the equivalent circuit or a load?

Comment: I assume you already have done these Thevenin equalent circuits previously. Its straight forward. Find Rth first by replacing all Sources to their equalent circuits. Find Voltage across M & N pins for Vth.

Comment: @copper.hat R7 is part of the given circuit.

Comment: Then you must include it in your calculation.

Comment: By inspection the equivalent resistance is \$10k || 10k || 15k\$.

Comment: @copper.hat so Rth is 10k/10k/15k = 3.75k yes?

Comment: If you do your computation correctly you will see that \$I(V4)=0\$. Then the Thevin equivalent voltage is straightforward to compute.

Comment: There are lots of ways of solving these circuits. Learn how to combine two Thevenin equivalents in parallel.

Comment: @NamHoang If \$R_7\$ is supposed to be part of the circuit within the black box that has just two nodes protruding, then your results are right. I get \$V_{_\text{TH}}=5\:\text{V}\$ (with M more positive than N) and \$R_{_\text{TH}}=3.75\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I didn't look over your process, though.

Answer (score -1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is way complicated than this one. In combination with the other answers, my answer is valuable.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foyGXV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ and \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_x\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_x
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I5, I3 == I4 + I5, I4 == I3 + I6, I2 == I1 + I6, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == V1/R3, I4 == (V3 - V2)/R4, 
   I4 == (0 - V3)/R5, V1 - V2 == Vx}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2,
    V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (R3 (R4 + R5) Vi + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi - R2 R3 Vx)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I2 -> (R3 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I3 -> (R2 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I4 -> (-R2 R3 Vi + R1 R3 Vx + R2 (R1 + R3) Vx)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I5 -> (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi - (R1 + R2) R3 Vx)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I6 -> (-R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi + (R1 + R2) R3 Vx)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V1 -> (R2 R3 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V2 -> -(((R4 + R5) (-R2 R3 Vi + R1 R3 Vx + R2 (R1 + R3) Vx))/(
    R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))), 
  V3 -> (R2 R3 R5 Vi - (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) R5 Vx)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_1\$ and letting \$\text{R}_3\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{V}_x\text{R}_1\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_3\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R3 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
  R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  R3 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R3 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
  R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  R3 -> Infinity]]

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 ((R4 + R5) Vi + R1 Vx))/(
  R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), R3 -> 0]]

Out[3]=Vi/R1 + Vx/(R4 + R5)

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R1 R2 (R4 + R5))/(R2 (R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R4 + R5))
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=5\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{1}{750}\approx0.00133333\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=3750\space\Omega\tag9$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the very well-motivated downvote, I really appreciate it.